# Export Virtual machine from VM box to physical disk as operating system

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have an virtual machine in VM VirtualBox and i would like to export it to an disk/flash disk as complete function operating system, so if i would start the pc with disk connected, it will boot to this system with all settings that were in VirtualBox. Is it somehow possible to do it? I was trying to found the solution, but i only found how to export the files, that are compatible only for another VirtualBox.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: If you can mount the virtual HDD within Windows there are numerous tools that would accomplish what you describe.  You might be able to use third-party disk imaging tools, from within the VM itself, and create an image that can be used to restore to a physical disk drive. This tool would have to be able to restore Windows installation to dissimilar hardware (also known as universal restore).

Comment: VirtualBox emulates by default old hardware. To graft it into a modern computer, you will need to solve many technical problems.